# EC2 python: can't open file '–m': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run command python –m . but I am getting error as

python: can't open file '–m': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I am on Ec2 the python version is 2.7

Comment: The text you've copied contains an en dash (`–`) instead of a hyphen (`-`). Type out `-m` manually.

Comment: @duskwuff yes this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested by @duskwuff, you are using the unicode char en dash `–` instead of hyphen `-`. Though they look same, they are different chars. Use hyphen instead of en dash.

```
$ –
-bash: $'\342\200\223': command not found

$ python –m
python: can't open file '–m': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

$ -
-bash: -: command not found

$ python -m
Argument expected for the -m option
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
```

Comment: Great help. I was copying from a book and didn't know that this could happen.

Had this error code ```can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```